# Design issue - how to propagate errors from server to client

Tags: java, validation, error-handling, architecture

i have a design question.

How should i propagate errors from a java server (accessed by REST API, JSON) to clients?

At the moment i throw exceptions. An exception contains an ERROR_TAG and variables. The exception is serialized, the http-return code is set to 422 for business and validation errors and 500 for technical or unexpected errors.

The serialized exception does not contain a text, only the tag (= kind of exception) and variables (= details, for example a customer number). So the client has to translate the exception to a readable format for the user.

A friend says this is a stupid behavior, he wants that the server answers with a full error message and in different languages. In my opinion i start to implement presentation layer concerns into the server... he argues that many clients have to implement the translations (redundant source)... in this case i would offer a default lib to do the translations or at least a translation properyfile which every client could use.

One more information about validation: The validation is encapsulated in a lib (= jar), which the server and the client use (so the server doesn't trust the client and no source is duplicated if the client wants to speed up the validation by local validation checks).

Any smart opinions about this design issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can use composite objects in which List<Error> errors is one member. On receiving: if ( !response.getErrors().isEmpty()){} ...

Comment: I think this is very opinion based. In my company we're sending a rough error message and code within response and full error stack traces are saved to log files. But this rather depends on who the consumers of your APIs are. For internal APIs it might be better to have more info, but on the other side your collegues can access the logs too. You definately don't want to spread your full tracebacks over non-techie users.

Comment: I already do this... validationexception contains a list of validationerrors. My question is about the language translation.

Comment: IMHO if your API renders errors localized or not depends on whether the normal output is localized. Codes and error keywords should be all english though.

Comment: At the moment nothing in the server is localized. Technical und unexpected (runtime) exceptions are fully written into the log, business exceptions not. The stacktrace is never send to the client (too much information about server internals). Codes and error keywords are in english.

Comment: maybe using json-encoded messages. what i do is return json responses, which always have one of two fields either error + localised error msg, or success + localised success message, plus any other data/parameters needed. This way the response and handling thereof is not tightly-coupled to a specific exception and serialisation (ie java )

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. So you think it is no problem to handle the translation on server side?